# Trying to write a script to download only grids from a web based microstrategy dashboard

Tags: javascript, html, excel, dashboard, microstrategy

I have a micro strategy dashboard which has couple of grids , few graphs and lot of drop downs and selector options , There is a functionality to export the entire thing into excel which gives a variable structure in excel every time. I would like to download only the grids present. I was able to download one of the grids with the grid name , but in case of multiple grids this would be as good as copy pasting these grids by hand in an excel . AT the end it is going to be a radio button on the dashboard to download all the grids available in it.  Following is the script :

```
  <html>
  <script>
  try{
  var sessionState = mstrApp.sessionState;
  var baseURL = '?
  evt=3132&src=mstrWeb.3132
     &executionMode=4&gridKey=W52,W75&rwExportMode=4&sessionState='
  baseURL = baseURL + sessionState + '&rwb=';
  var beanState = mstrApp.docModel.bs;
  baseURL = baseURL + beanState;
  document.getElementById("exportLink").href = baseURL
  }catch(err){
  document.getElementById("exportLink").href = ""
  }
  </script>
  <a id="exportLink" target="_blank" href=""><img height="30px" width="30px" 
  src="../Images/Excel_icon.png"/></a>
  </html>
```

Thanks a ton in advance for any help !!

Comment: Are the grids coming from some reports? My first suggestion would be to have reports that by default export to cvs or excel and have links to those reports. Or a similar solution with additional MSTR reports or documents.

Comment: @musico - yes the grids are sourcing from different reports. I have a number of dashboards and a radio button functionality would give me lesser to do ,I can simply plug it in.  Going to each report and then updating links is not desirable as long as it isn't the last resort , assuming that it'll be a lot of work as there are a large number of them . Thank you for your reply !

Comment: I'm not aware of any functionality that you can leverage to export a single grid from your document. In fact the code that you pasted just uses the default export for the document where it's attached. You will need to build a proper SDK solution for this requirement.